# Wifi automatically turn off when i open apps

Tags: wi-fi

How to solve this problem when i open apps on my phone my wifi automatically turn off

Comment: Would you please provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to check the apps you have installed as they shouldn't be doing that.  If it's just one app doing it uninstall it.  If it does that with any app it sounds like an issue with the phone itself.

You can try backing up your data and then factory resetting the phone, if the problem still persists then you have larger issues with it.